# If the weapon for divine bond is already magic, can a paladin add Keen to it at 5th level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin

The rules for [Divine Bond](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin), state:

> At 5th level, this spirit grants the weapon a +1 enhancement bonus.

It then goes on:

> For every three levels beyond 5th, the weapon gains another +1 enhancement bonus, to a maximum of +6 at 20th level. **These** bonuses can be added to the weapon, stacking with existing weapon bonuses to a maximum of +5, or they can be used to add any of the following weapon properties: axiomatic, brilliant energy, defending, disruption, flaming, flaming burst, holy, keen, merciful, and speed.

I'm unsure whether or not the emboldened "**These**" refers only to the bonuses beyond 5th level (the rules do not emphasise this word - I have done so for clarification).

In other words, at 5th level, can a paladin add one of the listed attributes to a magic weapon, or does the spirit simply add a +1 enhancement bonus?

The weapon must be magical in order to pay for the additional bonus, as clarified by:

> If the weapon is not magical, at least a +1 enhancement bonus must be added before any other properties can be added.

However, I am unsure whether the additional bonuses only come into play at levels 8, 11, 14, 17 and 20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, you can add a property to the weapon from any bonus, assuming it is already magical.

The main restriction here is stated in your question:

> If the weapon is not magical, at least a +1 enhancement bonus must be added before any other properties can be added.

This implies that any of the +1 bonuses could be converted to a property, except in the situation that the weapon is non-magical.

So, if you have a non-magical longsword, you have to give it a +1 before you can add any properties at all. However, if you had a +1 longsword, you could make that a +1 merciful longsword with the +1 you got from level 5

### However you may only add properties that you have enough plusses for

Speed would be out of the question for 5th level because it requires a +3 bonus equivalent. Keen, however, is fair game.